# Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, 18.10

I`m a complete noob. Just bought a Lenovo ideapad 330 17ch. Installed Ubuntu 18.10. Wored fine apart from wi-fi and touchpad. Then downloaded prerelease od 19.04. installed it and this solved the problem with wi-fi, but not with touchpad. My bloothoth mouse works fine. Please help. Thanks
I`ve found this: This touchpad id is "ELAN061F"

"To resolve this issue you need add a line in file:
drivers/input/mouse/elan_i2c_core.c

missing line:

{ "ELAN061F", 0 },"
But I really dont know how to make it.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the problem is editing the file the right way. You can use a text editor that will allow you to edit the particular file as root, so executing the editor in terminal with sudo might help. Dont try it with gedit though, it happens that gedit will say it is not allowed to use it in sudo mode... so what you do is, use one that is allready installed. I suggest, if you are not that familiar with terminal based text editors, to use nano, it allows usage of the mouse, which vi/vim does allow as well, but... not clicking in text, also, but this solution I am not that familiar with... you can use a command to simply append the specified line to the specified file, wouldnt know what kind of command it is, but I am just as curious if someone could help out! Chances are, using vi/vim or nano, you wont need sudo, but just use it to be safe... Also please specify the file path from root / that would help me, I am not that experienced myself, but if you right click elan_i2c_core.c and look into its properties, you will find the correct file path from root directory to the location of the file.

Comment: This is a kernel source file. After editing it compilation of a kernel is needed.